# CMake Block of targets compilation

Tags: cmake, compilation, target

I´m migrating a huge aplication from OMake to CMake. I need to define a block compilation depending on a parameter passed on make comand line (like on traditional make) for example:

```
add_executable(target_1 target_one.c)
add_executable(target_2 target_two.c)
add_executable(target_3 target_three.c)
...
add_executable(target_10 target_ten.c)

TARGETS_1 = target_1 target_2 target_3
TARGETS_2 = target_4 target_5 target_6
TARGETS_3 = target_7 target_8 target_9 target_10
...
...
if(args[1] == TARGETS_1) compile only TARGETS_1
else if(args[1] == TARGETS_2) compile only TARGETS_2
else if(args[1] == TARGETS_3) compile only TARGETS_3
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Just create a [custom target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) with the name `TARGETS_1` and make this target dependings (with [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html)) from target1, target_2 and target_3. That way invocation of `make TARGETS_1` will build all that targets.

Comment: I´ll do  this.  Thank you very much!

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Please ask a real question.